# Q: Cypress fixtures - cannot read property of undefined

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to use fixtures to hold data for different tests. This is an example of the code. When it gets to the second test I'm getting 'Cannot read property 'email' of undefined'.

Any ideas why and how I can get around that? I'm new to this and followed a course where they said the whole point of using fixtures in the 'before' was to have the data accessible to everything. Is that wrong?

Thank you

```js
describe('Example', function() {
  before(function() {
    cy.fixture('dataFile').then(function(dataJson) {
      this.dataJson = dataJson;
    });
  });

  it('name', function() {
    cy.log(this.dataJson.email);
  });
  it('name2', function() {
    cy.log(this.dataJson.email);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the below solution to make it work:

```js
describe('Example', function() {
  let testData;

  before(function() {
    cy.fixture('dataFile').then(function(dataJson) {
      testData = dataJson;
      return testData;
    });
  });

  it('name', function() {
    cy.log(testData.email);
  });
  it('name2', function() {
    cy.log(testData.email);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `before()` you have to use `beforeEach()` so that the fixture data is available to all your `it()` blocks:

```js
describe('Example', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    cy.fixture('dataFile').then(function(dataJson) {
      this.dataJson = dataJson;
    });
  });

  it('name', function() {
    cy.log(this.dataJson.email);
  });

  it('name2', function() {
    cy.log(this.dataJson.email);
  });
});
```